# InstallTask not found

Tags: spring, ant

I'm going through the Spring MVC tutorial. I have a build.xml and build.properties file as well as a simple jsp file. When I try to run ant, I get this error:

```
Buildfile: /<home>/dev/Spring/springapp/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/<home>/dev/Spring/springapp/build.xml:85: taskdef class org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask cannot be found
using the classloader AntClassLoader[/usr/local/apache-tomcat/current/lib/catalina-ant.jar]

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I looked in the catalina-ant.jar file, and sure enough there is no InstallTask class. Did this jar file change, since the spring tutorial was written? If so, where can I find the InstallTask.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is out of date - the [InstallTask](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/ant/InstallTask.html) has been deprecated in favour of the [DeployTask](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/ant/DeployTask.html).
Newer distributions no longer include the deprecated class.  You should be able to revise your buildfile simply by changing 'Install' to 'Deploy', something like:

```
<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
```